# Multiple div elements that have different number of div children using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape a webpage that has multiple div elements. Each  suppose to have a fixed number of other  children. However, sometimes, due to not entering an input by the admin,one of those children's divs is missed. Here 2 samples to give you a better idea:

```
//example 1
<div class = "row Book_Details">
<div class="class="col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="display:flex"></div>
<div class="class="col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="display:flex"></div>
</div>
```

//sample 2:

```
<div class = "row Book_Details">
<div class="class="col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="display:flex"></div>
<div class="class="col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="display:flex"></div>
<div class="class="col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="display:flex"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to exclude the parent  based on a threshold when it missed one of the children's divs? Let's say, I will find all of them and check if one of them has less number of children so I exclude it! Or may be filling the text of the missed one by a string value like NA

I am using Selenium and `driver.find_elements(('xpath',...)`. I tried to count how many children are under the parent DIV and then add some If statements to exclude that found one.

Here is my attempted code:

```
for match in driver.find_elements('xpath','//div[@class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12"]//div[@class="row Book_Details"]'): 
        while len(match.find_elements('xpath','.//*'))==17:
            ExperienceLevel= match.find_elements('xpath','//div[@class="col-md-4 col-lg-4"]')
```

Any guidance is much appreciated here!
Maybe this layout screenshot helps tp understand the challenge:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//div[@class='row Book_Details' and count(./div) > 2]
```